# How to navigate from one project storyboard to another project storyboard in Ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have two projects in  workspace, I want to navigate one project storyboard to another project storyboard.

Comment: Where can i find MyProjectBundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **storyboard references**. Drag an drop a storyboard reference from the side panel and connect it with your respective view controller. Select the storyboard reference and edit it's properties like the first/main view controller of it. Name the segue as usual and you'll be able to switch between multiple storyboards

P.S: make sure the all your storyboards has their entry points set!!

Comment: As I define I have two different projects storyboard in my workspace not in same project.

Comment: I have two projects in one workspace, both projects have their own storyboard now i want to navigate one storyboard to another storyboard.

Comment: it doesn't matter where your files are located as long as they are in a workspace. Have you tried my method ?

Comment: @DarkInnocence: you have to keep in my that you can only use storyboard references when targeting ios >= 9.

Comment: Yes i tried but it says ' **could not find storyboard name**'.

Comment: you also have to copy bundle resources and add all those up in build phases settings